# Pressure Canner vs pressure cooker

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, canning, pressure-cooker

I am wondering what the difference is between a pressure canner and a pressure cooker? Will they do the same thing? Isn't the difference mainly in the size e.g.: width of the bottom?? Thanx...

Answer (score 3):

A pressure cooker basically has two settings, high [(about 12.5 psi for electric](https://www.thekitchn.com/when-to-use-high-or-low-pressure-on-the-instant-pot-236432), and 15 psi for stovetop) and low (4 to 7 psi). There are no gauges to accurately specify the pressure in pressure cookers.

Pressure canners, on the other hand, are generally larger, and are equipped with accurate gauges so that the user can measure the exact pressure inside the pot.  It is this accurate measure of pressure (and time) that is necessary to safely can food.

Comment: I generally agree with the answer, but I'm wondering where the information about 12.5 psi "for electric" comes from, and what you mean by "for gas." As far as I know, standard pressure cookers tend to be designed with valves that target 15 psi, as that's the standard pressure (with temp ~250F) assumed by most recipes.